# Blazor WASM, bug with dotnet publish and events?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I'm having throubles with Blazor WASM and dotnet publish

I have a clean Blazor WASM .NET 6 project, and I added a little code to catch events

[image]

I debug the app with Visual Studio 2022 and after click on the titles I get this:

[image]

All working as expected

But when I do a

```
dotnet publish
```

And run the app I get:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? It's a bug?

Comment: How are you running the published app?

Comment: With VS Code "Live Server" extension (a simple static webserver) and also tried out with GitHub Pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you can consider this a bug, but when you publish your app, [MouseEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.mouseeventargs?view=aspnetcore-6.0) changes from a normal property with getter and setters:

```
public bool AltKey { get; set; }
```

to something like this, and `JsonSerializer` cannot serialize it anymore:

```
public bool AltKey
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    set
    {
        <AltKey>k__BackingField = value;
    }
}
```

As far as I can see you cannot turn this off either. Perhaps they didn't think anyone would try to serialize eventargs.

Now, as soon as the compiler can detect that you read a property, such as `var value = e.AltKey;`, it can no longer perform the optimization above and the property will appear in serialization.

Comment: Ok, thanks that allows me to understand the problem and do a workaround in my code. I wasn't doing serialization when I discovered. I did this example to simplify what I'm dealing with. I was doing a drag & drop event and sending the MouseEventArg to a Javascript function wich does some mouse/window calculations (Where I think there is an implicit serialization)

Comment: @Santiago: Yes, you are right, `MouseEventArg` is being serialized by the framework. Probably the best workaround is to store the properties you need in another object and pass that.